# Defining sine function via arclength

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

Suppose we attempt to define the sine function through the following way. Let
\begin{equation}
F(y) = \int_0^y \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
\end{equation}
for all $y \in [0,1]$ and $F(-y) = -F(y)$. This approach defines the arcsin function and in fact, $\lim_{y\to 1-}F(y)$ do exist, since $F(\cdot)$ is monotonic (and in fact, is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$).

Here is my question. To define sine function, we define $G : [-A,A] \to [-1,1]$ via $G(F(y)) = y$. I can prove that $G(\cdot)$ is differentiable on $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ but failed to prove differentiability at end points. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=F(y)$ and then $y=G(x)$. Note $F(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and hence $G(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$. From this, one obtains
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to{\frac{\pi}{2}}^-}G'(x)&=&\lim_{x\to{\frac{\pi}{2}}^-}\frac{G(\frac{\pi}{2})-G(x)}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}\\
&=&\lim_{y\to1^-}\frac{G(F(1))-G(F(y))}{F(1)-F(y)},x=F(y)\\
&=&\lim_{y\to1^-}\frac{1-y}{F(1)-F(y)}\\
&=&\lim_{y\to1^-}\frac{1}{F'(\xi)}, y<\xi<1\\
&=&\lim_{y\to1^-}\sqrt{1-\xi^2}\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}